# Twitter bootstrap accordion strange behavior

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, accordion

I am using the bootstrap accordion (collapse) in my project, but unfortunately the result is not the desire one. I have around 8 items in the accordion, some of them having lot of text inside (sometimes more than half a page).

I am trying to collapse/expand items in accordion, but the behavior is totally strange and unpredictable. I just copied the example on their site and added more items.
My expectations was that each time I click on a closed item it will open and the open div will receive focus. Sometimes I see page scrolling very fast and focus is positioned in a wrong place or item is opened but focus is too low on the page and title is not visible.

Any idea on how to handle accordion properly or what's the correct behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RdK8t/

It's taken directly from [the bootstrap example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) with extended content added to one of the elements.

The typical code is:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionParent"> <!-- start #accordionParent wrap -->


      <!-- start typical content group -->  
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionParent" href="#collapseOne">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                        content
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>  
       <!-- end typical content group -->


</div>  <!-- end accordionParent wrap -->
```

You could validate your page to ensure there isn't a nesting problem, and double check that if your aren't using the full bootstrap js file, make sure you are including the transitions plugin.

Hope this helps!